# Fullcalendar. Events in database don't appear in calendar

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I have created an instance of  Fullcalendar running from a database. Everything works fine except events on Monday And Thursday which appear in the database but not in the calendar. All the days of the week are treated the same in the code. How can this happen?
I have attached views of the database and the calendar. I have also included insert.php which is where I believe the problem lies

[View of calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlVdJ.png)[View of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiNMw.png)

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(1);
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","neil","souhami2");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("fullcalendar", $con);
$date = ($_POST['dowstart']);
$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "-1 days"));
$date3 = ($_POST['dowend']);
$date4 = str_replace('-', '/', $date3);
$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date4 . "+1 days"));
$error_message = "";


$titleErr = $equalErr = "";
$title = $start = $end = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $title = test_input($_POST["title"]);
  $start = test_input($_POST["start"]);
  $end = test_input($_POST["end"]);
  $dow = test_input($_POST["dow"]);
  $color = test_input($_POST["color"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
};

$one = $_POST["dow"][0];
$two = $_POST["dow"][1];
$three = $_POST["dow"][2];
$comma = $_POST["dow"][3];
$four = $_POST["dow"][4];
$five = $_POST["dow"][5];
$six = $_POST["dow"][6];
$comma = $_POST["dow"][7];
$eight = $_POST["dow"][8];
$nine = $_POST["dow"][9];
$ten = $_POST["dow"][10];
 $age=array("Mon"=>"1","Tue"=>"2","Wed"=>"3","Thu"=>"4","Fri"=>"5","Sat"=>"6","Sun"=>"0");


if($eight){
   $first = $one.$two.$three;
   $first = $age[$first];
   $second = $four.$five.$six;
   $second = $age[$second];
   $third = $eight.$nine.$ten;
   $third = $age[$third];
   $third = $first.$comma.$second.$comma.$third;
   $_POST["dow"] = $third;
}
else if($four){
   $first = $one.$two.$three;
   $first = $age[$first];
   $second = $four.$five.$six;
   $second = $age[$second];
   $second = $first.$comma.$second;
   $_POST["dow"] = $second;
}
else if($one){
   $first = $one.$two.$three;
   echo $one;echo $two;echo $three;
   $first = $age[$first];
   echo $first;
   $_POST["dow"] = $first;
};

$sql="INSERT INTO events (title, start, end, dow, dowstart, dowend, color)
      VALUES
  ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[start]','$_POST[end]','$_POST[dow]','$date','$date2','$_POST[color]')";



if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "1 record added";

header("location: index.html"); 

mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is process.php which fetches events:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

{
    $events = array();
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM events");
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $e = array();
        $e['id'] = $fetch['id'];    
        $e['start'] = $fetch['start'];
        $e['end'] = $fetch['end'];
        $e['title'] = $fetch['title'];
        $e['dow'] = $fetch['dow'];
        $e['ranges'] = [ array("dowstart" => $fetch['dowstart'],"dowend" => $fetch['dowend'])];
        $e['color'] = $fetch['color'];

        array_push($events, $e);
    }
    echo json_encode($events);
}
?>
```

This is the relevant section of index.html

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: JSON.parse(json_events),
        utc: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
                    selectable: true,
                    select: function() {window.location.href = "http://www.villagehall.westerdale.info/booking/"},
        droppable: true, 
        slotDuration: '00:30:00',
                    eventRender: function(event){
                         return (event.ranges.filter(function(pixies){ 
                         return (event.start.isBefore(pixies.dowend) &&
                       event.end.isAfter(pixies.dowstart));

                    }).length)>0;
                    },
        eventReceive: function(event){
            var title = event.title;
            var start = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                data: 'type=new&title='+title+'&startdate='+start+'&enddate='+end+'&zone='+zone,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    event.id = response.eventid;
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.responseText);

                }
            });
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
            console.log(event);
        },
```

Comment: If they are in the database, but do not show up afterwards, _that_ script (that should show them) might be more interesting.

Comment: that `header("location: index.html"); ` won't work btw, because you have some output before.

Comment: Jeff You might not think header("location: index.html"); doesn't work but it does. The previous outputs only work if you comment that line out. They are for editing purposes.

Comment: Added process.php to the snippet

Comment: still missing the _"script (that should show them)"_... (index.html?)

Comment: did you check that the missing events are in `$events` (and passed to ajax return)?

Comment: Added excerpt from index.html

Comment: Yes all the events are there in the output of process.php

Comment: and when gets `json_events` defined/filled/populated from process.php?

Comment: and since you are at it, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it now takes 5 questions to maybe get the crucial part of code to be able to help you.

Comment: "and when gets json_events defined/filled/populated from process.php?"                 I don't understand the question. Isn't that in the index.html code?

Comment: the events in fullCalendar get populated here: `events: JSON.parse(json_events)`. But we don't see how and when `json_events` gets set.

Comment: I assume it is done here `code`'echo json_encode($events);'`code` . There is no other relevant code. I can comment out all code I have not sent you and it still works perfectly but only for Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday and Saturday.

Comment: This bit?   $(document).ready(function() {

  var zone = "05:30"; 

 $.ajax({
  url: 'process.php',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: 'type=fetch',
        async: false,
        allDay: true,
        success: function(s){
         json_events = s;
        }
 });

Comment: yes, that's where the events get loaded. Now check if you got _all_ the events in `s` or in `json_events` in there.

Comment: I re-looked at your data in database. It seems like the data doesn't match with what is displayed in several cases: 
2018-09-29 "name49" shows up on 2018-09-30. 
Some others are the same. 
There is nothing shown on 2018-10-10, although there is data, and it's a wednesday.

Comment: You missed lines 17-24 in insert.php. The code there explains the behaviour you have observed. Without this fix events display a day earlier. If the data shows 2018-09-27 it will display on the 28th

Comment: This then sounds like a major timezone issue... that might double up when showing.

Comment: How can this be? I am not using a timezone.

Comment: mysql beeing in a different timezone than php and than Fullcalendar

Comment: Thank you it's working. Because I change the PHPMyAdmin timezone I think.